# Wrap exceeding content of combo box in available space?

Tags: java, swt

I have been working on an SWT project. I have a combo box whose values are set through database. I have set a fixed size for combo box but when a long string is set as an item for it, the width of combobox exceeds out of set size. I want the combo box to wrap the content by shifting the exceeding string to next line.

Here's my code:

```
String items[] = {"A","B","WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW","C"};
Combo combo =new Combo(comp, SWT.WRAP);
combo.setItems(items);
combo.select(0);
GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
combo.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to achieve **WRAP** in `SWT Combo`.

You may want to look at

http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/tablecombo/tablecombo.php

I am not sure `TableCombo` supports multi line items. But you can achieve that by using `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` on `TableViewer`.

Comment: Actually TableCombo is to provide some larger functionality which i don't need. I just want to wrap the string in multiple line. Anyways i will experiment it and get back to you. Thanks for your reply...

Answer (score 0):

`Combo` does not support `SWT.WRAP`. What you are describing is not possible through any of the standard widgets. This will have to be a completely custom control.

Comment: Can you plz guide me a way how to achieve that. Actually i am very new to SWT.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making use of the `GridLayout` on the parent composite, `GridData` with `widthHint` can be set as layout data to the Combo control. However, dropdown/hints would still overflow the set width